# Is it possible to create a picklist of Record Types?

Tags: picklist, lookup, record-type

I need to create a picklist on an object, where i can select record types that are filtered by a lookup field.

Example:

1. Accounts object has a lookup field for Custom_Object B
2. Account also has a picklist where I can select "Custom_Object B" record types, that are filtered by the selection in the lookup field.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Till today, Salesforce OOTB functionality doesn't allow to select recordtypes based on filtered by a lookup field.

Currently, OOTB recordtypes are displayed based on profile permission.

You might need to think for custom development.